# Angular HttpErrorResponse Put Operation

Tags: java, angular, typescript, quarkus

I have a Quarkus server and I want to add a school to my table that shows database data, but I get HttpErrorResponse status 0. I also have a CORS filter. When I update something, it does work and save the changed data in the database. I get the following error:

[image]

SchoolResource

```js
package rest;

import dao.SchoolDao;
import model.School;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.List;

@Path("school")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Transactional
public class SchoolResource {

    @Inject
    SchoolDao dao;

    @GET
    public List<School> getAll() {
        return dao.getAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public School getById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        return dao.getById(id);
    }

    @PUT
    public void save(School school) {
        dao.save(school);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void delete(School school) {
        dao.delete(school);
    }

}
```

SchoolDao

```js
package dao;

import model.School;

import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.List;

@Dependent
public class SchoolDao {

    @Inject
    EntityManager em;

    public List<School> getAll() {
        return em.createQuery("select s from School s", School.class).getResultList();
    }

    public School getById(int id) {
        return em.find(School.class, id);
    }

    public void save(School school) {
        em.merge(school);
    }

    public void insert(School school) {
        em.persist(school);
        em.flush();
    }

    public void delete(School school) {
        em.remove(school);
    }

}
```

insert-component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { School } from '../model/school';
import { SchoolService } from '../school.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-insert',
  templateUrl: './insert.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./insert.component.css']
})
export class InsertComponent implements OnInit {

  name = "";
  street = "";
  
  school: School = {id: -1, name: "", street: ""};

  constructor(private schoolService: SchoolService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  save(): void {
    this.school = {id: -1, name: this.name, street: this.street};
    this.schoolService.save(this.school).subscribe(e => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/dashboard");
    });
  }

}
```

service.ts

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { School } from './model/school';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SchoolService {

  url = "http://localhost:8080/school"

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<School[]> {
    return this.http.get<School[]>(this.url);
  }

  getById(id: number): Observable<School> {
    const url = `${this.url}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<School>(url);
  }

  save(school: School): Observable<School> {
    return this.http.put<School>(this.url, school);
  }

  delete(id: number): Observable<School> {
    const url = `${this.url}/${id}`;
    return this.http.delete<School>(this.url);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: *When I update something, it does work and save the changed data in the database.* - keep doing this thing and it should be fine no?

Comment: @ScaryWombat No it doesn't work, because when I update something, the object already exists, if I insert something I need to create a new one.

Comment: The error seems to be related to SSL certificates, and this [discussion on github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4839) might help.

Comment: @tromgy This error shows up often, but other things work anyway

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).